# How to block call overridden method from Child

Tags: java, events, block, extends

For example I have two classes.

```
public class PActivity {
...
    @Override
    public boolean OnEventSocket(PMSocketEvent a_iEvent)
        ...
        handled = OnEventSocket(...);
    }
}
```

Second class:

```
public class PMenu extends PActivity {
    @Override
    public boolean OnEventSocket(PMSocketEvent a_iEvent)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

How can I block the calling method from the second class?

Sometimes I want call the method `OnEventSocket` from the base class.

I have many classes like `PMenu`, so I have to make the change in `PActivity`

Comment: you can do so by `super.OnEventSocket(....)` inside the methods of the sub classes.

Comment: What do you mean by "block the calling method"?

Comment: Do you want to call `OnEventSocket` from the superclass using instance of a subclass?

Comment: For example my android activity is in PMenu, but i do not want call method from PMenu, but from PActivity.

Comment: And call method is only in PActivity class

Comment: In PMenu is only overridden implementation

Comment: If you want to call method from PActivity then you need an instance of PActivity.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to call the overridden method of superclass](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15668032/how-to-call-the-overridden-method-of-superclass)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a kind of [template method pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern).

Essentially, rather than have an overridable public method, you override a protected method which is called by the public method. This allows you to do whatever checks you need to before invoking the overridden method.

```
public class PActivity {
...
    public final boolean onEventSocket(args)
    {
        if (method_should_be_called)
        {
            eventSocketImpl(args);
        }
    }

    protected boolean eventSocketImpl(args)
    {
        // default behaviour
    }
}

public class PMenu extends PActivity {
    @Override
    protected boolean eventSocketImpl(args)
    {
        // overridden behaviour
    }
}
```

You should be able to make this work without changing any of your `PMenu` implementations, with two drawbacks:

- You will have a public method which should be protected
- You will have to keep the current method names as they are, which may be confusing.

Comment: But I have I think 30 classes like PMenu, so I must change name OnEventSocket to eventSocketImpl everywhere?

Comment: I want to avoid this situation

Comment: @asus9e This is what I meant by my final two bullet points. You *could* keep it as it is now but that would mean your "entry point" method (my `public` one) would need to change name. Depending on how many places in the code this is called, this may be more or less work than changing all of your `PMenu`s.

Comment: Okay, I understand :) Thanks :) This function i call only once in PActivity