# If parent and child class are having same methods and i am using the reference of parent class to store the object of child class

Tags: java, polymorphism, overriding

Parent class

```java
class Animal {
    public void sound() {
        System.out.println("Grr");
    }
}
```

Child class

```java
class Dog extends Animal {
    public void sound() {
        System.out.println("Woof");
    }
}
```

Calling class

```java
class Callings {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Animal a = new Dog();
        a.sound();
    }
}
```

Output is - "Woof"

My concern is--> I have read till now that if we use the parent class reference and point to object to child class then using the reference of parent class we can only access the data members and methods of the parent class only, if this is true then output of above code should be "Grr". But the output is "Woof" can any one explain why.

Comment: Unless you use `super` inside the child class, then the call would go to the child class itself in this case.

Comment: This is the _meaning_ of the term "polymorphism".

Answer (score 1):

Even you are creating and object for `Animal` but the instance is type of `Dog`, you can create an instance of a child class and assign to the type of parent.

When you call a method, it should be defined in the parent class and if it is overridden in child then the child method will be called else the parent's method will be called.

You can check the type of the instance by printing the class type of the instance `a` by using `System.out.println(a.getClass().getName());` which will print `Dog`

Answer (score 0):

`Dog` knows it is a `Dog`, even if you call it an `Animal`.

Check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15668032/15777370) for more details.